# TypeError when using if statement to check index length when scraping and stripping address

Tags: python, web-scraping

**Update - Solved**

I have solved this as I realized I need a len function, not index function (and also was using int).  Solution was:

```
 address = addressChunk[0] if len(addressChunk) == 3 else '-'
    addresses.append(address)
```

**Original Text**

I am scraping a website and the business address generally follows [Address, Province Code, Postal Code], however sometimes the address is entered like [Address Province Code, Postal Code] or some variation that is less than an index of 2 (assuming it goes 0, 1, 2).

I have the following code, to strip the respective values from their index in the list based on commas, and add it to a variable if the list index equals 2, otherwise it should display "-", but I'm getting the below error.  Note that the code works on normally formatted addresses when the if statements are removed.

```
# initiate storage
addresses = []
provinces = []
postalCodes = []

# grab container html with regex to find randomized result id
companies_div = soup.find_all('div', {'id': re.compile('result-id-.*')})

        for x in companies_div:

                #extract address class and split by comma
                addressChunk = x.find('div', class_='result__address').text.split(',')

                # assign first index (address) to addresses list if index equals 2
                address = addressChunk[0] if int(addressChunk.index) == int(2) else '-'
                addresses.append(address)

                # same as above but for second index
                province = addressChunk[1] if int(addressChunk.index) == int(2) else '-'
                provinces.append(province)

                postalCode = addressChunk[2] if int(addressChunk.index) == int(2) else '-'
                postalCodes.append(postalCode)
```

However, I end up with the following error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

Note that when I remove the "int" from the formula, it results in even properly formatted addresses showing up as "-".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update - Solved**

I have solved this as I realized I need a len function, not index function (and also was using int).  Solution was:

```
 address = addressChunk[0] if len(addressChunk) == 3 else '-'
    addresses.append(address)
```